# html5 consuming webservices

Tags: jquery, html, silverlight

I'm developing a web page for a customer using the Silverlight application for dynamic photo content that can be updated in a database. The Silverlight application has an animation, and once you click in a photo it takes you to the details of that photo.

Now the client wants this to work on an iPad, but Silverlight is not supported by iOS. What would be the best way to solve this?

I thought of using HTML5 or jQuery, but I don't know if these techologies can get the photos from a WCF service. What do you think would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2008/02/calling-wcf-service-from-javascript.html

You could likely simplify the JSON services by using jQuery's built in capabilities, since you'll likely want to use jQuery later anyway to make the U[I/X] more appealing.